# readFileSync strips out the metadata in the png file

Tags: node.js

so I'm trying to read a png file into string,

```
const defaultIcon = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync("defaultIcon.png")).toString('base64');
```

guess what, the "data:image/png;base64," in the beginning of the icon image  is missing.
So what's the correct way to do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the png file doesn't contain such string (and it's normal behaviour). You are confusing it with data URL scheme used in HTML to inline data (such as images).

If you want to put in HTML, simply prepend `defaultIcon` with `data:image/png;base64,`, so it's will be like:

```
const imgNode = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + defaultIcon + '" alt="icon">'
```

See more on data URL scheme [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) (especially part 4. examples).

Comment: actually I'm testing in the node server side, png file itself has "png file signature", but let me read more into the links you gave, thx.